# Sorting event in gridview not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I googled a lot of times but don't have any userful link for my solution. I have AllwSorting="true" and OnSort function. Today I post this question, thanks for all your help.
This is my ASCX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwCus" runat="server" CssClass="gridview" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="false" OnRowCommand="RowCommand" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gvwCus_OnSorting">
  <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="4%">
        <HeaderTemplate>STT</HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="<%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="12%" DataField="field1" HeaderText="Field1_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
     <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="30%" DataField="field2" HeaderText="Field2_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
     <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="31%" DataField="field3" HeaderText="Field3_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
     <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="20%" DataField="field4" HeaderText="Field4_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     <asp:CommandField HeaderStyle-Width="2%" ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/Images/detail.png" ShowSelectButton="true" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my code behind: ASCX.CS, I have gvwCus_OnSorting function for Sort event, but don't have any event handled when I click on the header of gridview.

```
protected void gvwCus_OnSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
   DataBind(e);
}

private void DataBind(GridViewSortEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   var dataOracle = new DataOracle();
   var data = dataOracle.GetDataTable();
   if(eventArgs != null)
   {
      data.DefaultView.Sort = eventArgs.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(eventArgs.SortExpression);
   }
   gvwCustom.DataSource = data;
   gvwCustom.DataBind();
}

private string GetSortDirection(string column)
{
string sortDirection = "DESC";
string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

if (sortExpression != null)
{
    if (sortExpression == column)
    {
        string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
        if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "DESC"))
        {
            sortDirection = "ASC";
        }
    }
}

ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

return sortDirection;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: How do you know the event is not firing?

Comment: @EmmadKareem: I put breakpoints on gvwCus_OnSorting function.

Comment: So does the grid sort the data but the event is not firing? Where is your bind code?

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Bind data is the DataBind function. The data is: data=dataOracle.GetDataTable(). I googled that when i click on header, the event run to gvwCus_OnSorting function breakpoint but my code don't fire. That's my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not setting **SortExpression** for the columns you want to sort. Add SortExpression, you will see hyperlinks for each column. Clicking on those links will fire sort event. After adding sortexpression your boundfields should look like:

```
 <asp:BoundField SortExpression="field1" HeaderStyle-Width="12%" DataField="field1" HeaderText="Field1_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
 <asp:BoundField SortExpression="field2" HeaderStyle-Width="30%" DataField="field2" HeaderText="Field2_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
 <asp:BoundField SortExpression="field3" HeaderStyle-Width="31%" DataField="field3" HeaderText="Field3_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
 <asp:BoundField SortExpression="field4" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" DataField="field4" HeaderText="Field4_Header" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

Rendered headers should look like below:

[image]